# Logitech keyboard periodically "locks up"

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm on Windows 7 with a wired logitech G15 keyboard connected via USB.

If I hit the left "control" key twice in succession the keyboard goes into haywire mode:

The lights on the keyboard that indicate caps lock, scroll lock, and num lock start blinking in a cyclical fashion (caps lock lights up, then it goes off and scroll lock lights up, then it goes out and num lock lights up -- repeat ad infinitum).

When this happens the keyboard is COMPLETELY unresponsive.  Nothing I do works... typing, alt-tab, windows key, smashing my face on the keyboard - no response.

Hitting double control again does nothing -- the only way I've found to exit this mode is by smashing my hand over and over on the left side of the keyboard until the mode turns off.  I have no idea which key combination it is -- and I've tried many.  I just smash and smash and finally the keyboard works again.

I want to disable whatever stupid mode this is... because it really messes things up when I'm playing games that use the control key, or keys near the control key :/

No amount of googling or searching superuser.com has helped.

Comment: Does the problem persist after you click the LGS icon in the system notification area and select "exit"?

Comment: Um I don't know what "LGS" is, but the problem still persists after clicking exit on "Logitech Mouse and Keyboard" and the logitech control panel.

Comment: Have you tried changing macro sets (m1, m2, or mr)?